# Detecting if viewModel property changes without refreshing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, knockout.js

I have a property in my viewModel seeing if my application is either open or closed. Based on that variable it will show a different interface to the user (open hours if closed or the actual application).

My question is is there a way to check and see if that variable has changed in the viewmodel and if it has refresh the page?

My viewModel property looks kind of like this

```
viewModel.Open = ko.observable(this.base.get('Status'));
```

I was playing with a timer function, but I'm not really keen on putting a function like that within my createViewModel.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but that is the purpose of having "observable" properties. The variable will *tell you* when it is changing versus you having to *ask it*. You would want to refresh the page within a subscription on that observable.

Comment: @Origineil Yes, I do have an observable so I can tell when it's changing, but maybe I'm not understanding how to trigger a change when that value changes, such as refreshing the page if that value changes to closed..

Comment: @Origineil, also, it is just grabbing that variable once when it loads the page. So if it changes and the page refreshes then yes it will be able to tell that variable has changed, but not if no actions happen to the page.

Comment: The section [Explicitly subscribing to observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) covers "listening" to changes against the observable, but I gather you are asking more of how to "poll" a datasource for a potential value change after the page has loaded or otherwise fetch the current "status" from a datasource dynamically.

Comment: @Origineil I was just looking at that page and I'm not sure if any of those methods are going to work because again it seems that they are going to need a page refresh in order to work. And yes, I guess that is what I am asking. I'm still trying to figure out the best way to do this, all I have to go on is that it needs to refresh if the status changes.

Comment: That's what the two-way data binding of Knockout is about. You connect Javascript logic and data to your HTML, and Knockout updates it whenever needed. If you have a `<div data-bind="visible: Open">We're open!</div>`, it automatically becomes visible when `Open` changes from `false` to `true`, and vice-versa. If you haven't, try out the interactive tutorials at http://learn.knockoutjs.com - they should make things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for:

```
viewModel.Open.subscribe(function(val) {
    // React to change.
}));
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html